# Optimising a mongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

I have a huge collection of documents, that is ,generally speaking, meant to store millions of documents.

In general a typical document may be quite complex and dynamic, but there are a few constant fields that should be present in each of them. Those fields include: `GlobalDeviceStatus`, `ManualTests`, `SemiAutomaticTests`, `AutomaticTests`. All the three types of tests are represented by arrays of objects. Each such object may contain quite a few fields but there are again some constant ones. These are `componentName` and `componentTestStatus`.

```
{
    "data": {
        "globalDeviceStatus": false,
        "qaOfficerID": 12121,
        "ManualTests": [{
                "componentName": "camera",
                "componentTestStatus": true,
                "x": 10
            },
            {
                "componentName": "wifi",
                "componentTestStatus": false,
                "mnum": 711
            }
        ],
        "SemiAutomaticTests": [{
                "componentName": "someComponent",
                "componentTestStatus": true,
                "someParameter": true
            },
            {
                "componentName": "oneMoreComponent",
                "componentTestStatus": false
            }
        ],
        "AutomaticTests": [{
                "componentName": "anotherComponent",
                "componentTestStatus": true
            },
            {
                "componentName": "someVeryImportantComponent",
                "componentTestStatus": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "userID": 1
}
```

Each document represents a test. If the value of `GlobalDeviceStatus` turns out to be `false` then the test failed. This also means that its json is expected to contain at least one failed component (tests with `GlobalDeviceStatus` equal to `true` on the contrary, do not contain failed components which is quite logical). 
What I need is to calculate a number of failures for each component, that's as my output I need something like this:

```
{
    "componentName": 120,
    "someOtherComponentName": 31
}
```

Every componentName may only belong to one test type. That's to say, if in one document it's in `SemiAutomaticTests` tests it cannot migrate to `AutomaticTests` in another one.

To do such calculations I use the following mongo pipe:

```
COUNT_CRASHES = [
            {
                "$match": {
                    "$or": [{
                        "data.ManualTests.componentTestStatus": false
                    }, {
                        "data.AutomaticTests.componentTestStatus": false
                    }, {
                        "data.SemiAutomaticTests.componentTestStatus": false
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                "$project": {
                    "tests": {
                        "$concatArrays": [{
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$data.ManualTests",
                                "as": "mt",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": ["$$mt.componentTestStatus", false]
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$data.AutomaticTests",
                                "as": "at",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": ["$$at.componentTestStatus", false]
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$data.SemiAutomaticTests",
                                "as": "st",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": ["$$st.componentTestStatus", false]
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "$unwind": "$tests"
            }, {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$tests.componentName",
                    "count": {
                        "$sum": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

It returns the data in a format different from the one specified above but it's not that important, what really matters right now is that it takes about 7 seconds and sometimes twice as much (~ 14 seconds) to return. That's with 350k documents in the DB.

I would like to reduce the time as much as possible.

Comment: I'm unclear about your goal state. In the example document, you have `"componentName": "camera"`, but in your desired output you have `"componentName": 120`. How are these two connected? What is the significance of `"someOtherComponentName": 31`? Could you please provide an example output that you expect to be generated from the example document?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha Oh yeah now I see it's a little vague. Well actually the desired output should go like this: all keys correspond to the names of crashed components and all values are numbers of crashes. That's, the `someComponent` crashed 120 times and `someOtherComponent` crashed 31 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you restructure your documents into something where `"ManualTests"`,`"AutomaticTests"` and `"SemiAutomaticTests"` would become field values as opposed to fields themselves (which would likely allow for a leaner pipeline) you would probably need to create three indexes like this to speed up the `$match`:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ "data.ManualTests.componentTestStatus": 1 })
db.collection.createIndex({ "data.AutomaticTests.componentTestStatus": 1 })
db.collection.createIndex({ "data.SemiautomaticTests.componentTestStatus": 1 })
```

Also note that your projection can be shortened into:

```
"$project": {
    "tests": {
        "$filter": {
            "input": { "$concatArrays": [ "$data.ManualTests", "$data.AutomaticTests", "$data.SemiAutomaticTests" ] },
            "as": "t",
            "cond": {
                "$eq": ["$$t.componentTestStatus", false]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and then use "explain" to verify how the pipeline engine is executing the query:    collection.explain().aggregate().